# Rewriting connection method to utilize Rx

Tags: rx-java, rxandroidble

I'm rewriting a method in a library to utilize Rx. The below code example is the original method.

```
public void connect(ConnectionListener connectionListener) {

    //......

    RxBleDevice device = mRxBleClient.getBleDevice(builder.toString());

    mEstablishedConnection = device.establishConnection(mContext, false)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnError(throwable -> {
                throwable.printStackTrace();
                connectionListener.onFailed();
                Log.d(TAG, "Error establishing a connection" + throwable.getMessage());
            })
            .subscribe(rxBleConnection -> {
                mConnection = rxBleConnection;
                connectionListener.onConnected();
                setNotifications();
                Log.d(TAG, "Connection established. Status: " + device.getConnectionState().toString());
            }, throwable -> {
                if (throwable != null) {
                    throwable.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
}
```

My first go was to return a `Subscription` instead of saving it to `mEstablishedConnection`. This would allow the user to unsubscribe to trigger a disconnect:

```
public Subscription connect() {

    //..

    RxBleDevice device = mRxBleClient.getBleDevice(builder.toString());

    return device.establishConnection(mContext, false)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnError(throwable -> {
                throwable.printStackTrace();
                Log.d(TAG, "Error establishing a connection" + throwable.getMessage());
            })
            .flatMap(rxBleConnection -> {
                mConnection = rxBleConnection;
                return Observable.empty();
            })
            .subscribe(o -> {
                setNotifications();
                Log.d(TAG, "Connection established. Status: " + device.getConnectionState().toString());
            }, throwable -> {
                if (throwable != null) {
                    throwable.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
}
```

The issue with the above is that I can not properly propagate errors back to the caller, which would be nice to do. How can I rewrite this method to make it reactive, letting the caller receive errors, and not just return an `RxBleConnection`, which is a 3rd party class?

Answer (score 1):

The proper answer is mostly depending on what interface you want to achieve. You can wrap the `RxBleConnection` inside your own interface.
It could like like this:

```
public Observable<YourWrapperClass> connect() {
    RxBleDevice device = // ...
    return device.establishConnection(context, false)
        .doOnNext(connection -> {
            setNotifications(connection) // pass the connection to setNotifications()
            mConnection = connection // store the mConnection if it is a must - in the reactive approach objects are meant to be passed instead of stored 
        })
        .map(connection -> new YourWrapperClass(connection))
}
```

Here the caller will be responsible for subscribing to the `Observable` (thus will be able to unsubscribe) and will not know of the internals (`RxBleConnection`).

Comment: This is what I was thinking. I will give this a go.